# NTP time synchronization failed : Missing ntpdate and sntp commands Webmin

Tags: ntp, webmin

There is a problem with syncing time with the NTP server in Webmin, This is the error:

```
NTP time synchronization failed: Missing ntpdate and sntp commands
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for me was installing ntp and ntpdate,

```
sudo apt-get install ntp ntpdate
```